# Dropdown is cropped while doing hover using transform

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, transform

Actually I want to achieve a dropdown,in which each of the cards having three dots icon and after clicking in the icon i want a dropdown which should be fully visible after clicking that icon. For hovering the cards I am using `transform: translateY(-3px);` in the `card-body` class and for the dropdown I am using `transform: translate3d(31px, 23px, 0px);`. Its working properly if I don't have card in the below of the card which i have hovered [image: See this Image] . But if I have cards exact below that card and I click on the three dots icon for dropdown so its showing like this [image: refer this image for the actual problem] . Can someone please help me out. I think code snippet won't run properly but you can refer the code and picture to understand what is happening actually And if you want any more input so do let me know. Thanks in Advance !!

```css
.card-body{
    height:150px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.75rem 0.80rem 1rem 1.25rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px 1px #A0A0A059;
    border: 0.25px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 7px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.card-body:hover {
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    transform: translate3d(31px, 23px, 0px); 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    will-change: transform;
}
.dropdown-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2cfd6;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card-body pb-0">
            <div class="row float-right ds-icon-container">
              <div class="btn-group float-right p-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle p-0"
                  [ngClass]="pipelineOverview.status === 'active' ? 'btn-green' : 'btn-red'">
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group float-right p-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-transparent dropdown-toggle p-0" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <!-- <i class="icon-settings"></i> -->
                  <img class="three-dots" src="../../assets/icons/icons8-menu-vertical-50.png" alt="Vertical Dots">
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" x-placement="bottom-end">
                  <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="ds-icon-start"></i>Start</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="ds-icon-restart"></i>Restart</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="ds-icon-stop"></i>Stop</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="populateDataInEdit(pipelineOverview)"><i class="ds-icon-edit" ></i>Edit/Preview</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="ds-icon-healthcheck"></i>Health Check</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: You have to set position 'relative' to the parent container with z-index, and then set absolute position to drop-down content. it will surely work then

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a z-index issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Because the elements are rendered later, they are stacked on top of the elements rendered before. Your menu is nested in a lower plane, and is displaying underneath other elements. Increasing z-index to a value higher than the other ones you want it to overlap, should resolve the issue.

tl;dr:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    z-index:9999
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `z-index` property to the items of drop-down menu or to the menu itself... You can even define Z axis for the element in `transform` also, If it doesn't works then try for `overflow` properties also... Kindly check it!

Comment: Thank you but z-index is not working. Can you explain me more where to add these other properties?

Comment: You have to set position 'relative' to the parent container with z-index and then set drop-down absolute position. it will surely work then

Comment: problem is that I can't judge your CSS by your snippet... Can you kindly share a fiddle? or try improving snnipet's answer so that I can edit it